# React native: Easiest way to implement a sign-up form

Tags: android, forms, reactjs, authentication, react-native

In react-native, what is the easiest way to implement a sign-up form? My current implementation involves a `this.refs.` object, but it doesn't really work and I can't seem to install one easy one. I use mobx, but don't need state-management system for this, as these values will always be sent between pages.

So, what is the easiest way to implement a sign-up form in react-native?

Comment: Is this going to be a single page or a multi page signup form?

Comment: Currently a single page sign-up form. But what's the difference to a multi-page sign-up form?

Comment: Well, if it's a single page, you can just use the `onChangeText` prop of TextInput to pass in a function and save the value of each form into the state. If you were using a multi page sign up form, I was going to recommend moving the values of the form out of local state and into some type of data architecture such as redux..